# JavaScript/CSS: Remove white space when copying

Tags: javascript, spam, email-address

I'm currently exploring ways to hide mail addresses from spam bots. I don't want to insert pictures. JavaScripting to hide addresses and decrypt them onclick is a neat option, but then I also want people to be able to hightlight the address and then copy (+paste) it in their preferred mail client.

So I came up with the idea to insert *span*s with "user-select: none", so this will prevent the user from highlighting it, but it will still be copied (at least in Chrome).

I don't want to use a popup as suggested in another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript). What I could imagine is a small popover below when hovering over the link ... something like "Send mail" and when you hover over it, a small box will appear below with the correct mail address decrypted right then by JavaScript. The downside is that users might not be aware of this method and fail to find the address.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A posible thing you could do is a button that when clicked puts the decrypted email adress onto the clipboard. If you properly lable the button it should not be hard for users to see what its for. Imgur uses a similar button for getting image links and so does imageshack if I recall correctly.

Comment: Naaa, manipulating users' clipboard is not a very good option.